# Get list of numbers in python without using numpy

Tags: python

Is there a way to get list of numbers in python without using numpy.
Example,

```
asd = ['926', '927', '928', '929', '930', '931']
```

I have a list above which are typed manually.. but can not put a range like (926 to 931) and get the list?

Any help?

Comment: `asd = [str(i) for i in range(926, 932)]`

Comment: Why would you not use numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `range` + `map`,

```
In [1]: list(map(str,range(926, 932)))
Out[1]: ['926', '927', '928', '929', '930', '931']
```

Answer (score 1):

`asd = [str(i) for i in range(926, 932)]`

square brackets `[...]` make it return a list

`i for i in range(x, y)` returns every value between x and y, inclusive of x and y

`str(i)` converts `i` to a string so you get the quotes around it

Thus, `asd = ['926', '927' ... '931', '932']`